# How to generate QR code with logo, without overlapping QR codes in behind?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I dont want any QR codes hidden behind my logo. I want to generate QR with logo intially.

```
QrImage(
                    embeddedImage: const AssetImage('assets/images/444.png'),
                    embeddedImageStyle: QrEmbeddedImageStyle(
                      size: const Size.square(95),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: whiteColor,
                    data: widget.data!,
                    version: QrVersions.auto,
                    size: 200.0,
                    errorCorrectionLevel: QrErrorCorrectLevel.Q,
                  ),
```

=====================================================
With this code, my QR code is hiding behind logo.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter hasn't been in active development recently.

You can use https://github.com/imrhk/qr.flutter as it contains some modifications in the original plugin including a property `blendEmbeddedImage` which originally comes from https://github.com/gibahjoe/qr.flutter

I have raised a PR on qr_flutter github repo but it hasn't been merged yet.